# ios background location services arrow disappears when not moving

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I built this app which is tracking the users position even when running in background. I use the CLLocationManagers method

```
startUpdatingLocation
```

I set the CLLocationManager to

```
desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
distanceFilter=250
```

Everything works fine in foreground and in background. But when I don't move the device for a longer period (hours) I can see that the location arrow disappears. When I switch back to my app I can see that the arrow comes back immediately and that the app did NOT crash. Is this a "feature" of the LocationManager I don't know? Did the LocationManager went into some kind of "standby"? This should NOT be an issue with the app running not in foreground since I can travel with it for an hour and it gives me a perfect track.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a feature. As given in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) location manager object manages power aggressively by turning off hardware when it is not needed. Turning off GPS hardware can lead to significant power savings.

Comment: I would not expect the location arrow to disappear if the position was determined only by wifi/cell. From my understanding the arrow does not stand for gps but for location service (regardless if this is done by gps, cell or wifi or any combination). Besides that I would expect the arrow to appear again once I am moving out of the distanceFilter radius.

Comment: I found the property "pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically" of the "CLLocationManager" class which seems to solve my problem when set to NO.

Comment: Yeah. You can make use that property if your app is for iOS 6.0 or later. But default value for that property is set to YES to improve the battery life. U can make use of **'activityType'** property to determine when to pause the location updates.